How to change the whole background color of a context menu?
I created a context menu in a class, which is derived from CView. I want the background of the popup to appear yellow. I tried the following:
CMenu menu;
menu.CreatePopupMenu();

InsertMenu(menu, 0, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_STRING | MF_ENABLED | MF_OWNERDRAW, 1, L"Item 1");
InsertMenu(menu, 0, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_STRING | MF_ENABLED , 2, L"Item 2");

CBrush m_BKBrush;
m_BKBrush.CreateSolidBrush(0x00ffee/*color*/);
MENUINFO mnInfo;
memset(&mnInfo, 0, sizeof(MENUINFO));
mnInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MENUINFO);
mnInfo.fMask = MIM_BACKGROUND;
mnInfo.hbrBack = m_BKBrush;
::SetMenuInfo(menu, &mnInfo);
m_BKBrush.Detach();

menu.TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, point.x, point.y, view);


As this is an owner-drawn window, the whole background is yellow, as it should appear. But the first item (the first string) is not displayed anymore.
If I don't have an owner-drawn menu, all items are displayed, but only the item's background color is yellow (see code and picture below):
InsertMenu(menu, 0, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_STRING | MF_ENABLED , 1, L"Item 1");
InsertMenu(menu, 0, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_STRING | MF_ENABLED , 2, L"Item 2");


Whether I use AppendMenu or InsertMenu doesn't make any difference.
How can I achieve both, complete yellow background as well as all strings displayed? Thanks a lot :)

For an owner-drawn menu, you have to write the code to draw each item. It's a potentially long-winded process and you'll be best off deriving your own class from CMenu, so you can override the OnDrawItem member function (or whatever does the operation).

The function in the CMenu class you'll have to override in your derived class is this one: virtual void DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct);.

Check the documentation of the Win32 SetMenuInfo() function. The CMenu class makes It  available too.  If all you want is change the background color you can avoid an owner-draw implementation.

If you don't need the space at the left (for check-marks) you can set the MNS_NOCHECK style

Perhaps a Visual Manager is interfering with the drawing of your menus. See CMFCVisualManager documentation and related classes. I am not programming MFC anymore, but some years ago, I had to do similar things and I remember I got stuck into the same situation.
